# how to change openid connect idtoken's iss

Tags: kubernetes, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I deployed wso2 IS 5.3.0 in docker. I set it up for openid connect authentication. I tried to have kubernetes to work with it for authentication. But it turns out to have problem with iss field in idtoken. The payload part of the token looks like below after decode:

```
{"exp":1487335376,"sub":"admin","azp":"Dibo_uMHzySCIxrf55uvMGWjGEUa","at_hash":"_8q5TmtJRsdEj4V_dL4-Zg","aud":["Dibo_uMHzySCIxrf55uvMGWjGEUa"],"iss":"https:\/\/localhost:9443\/oauth2\/token","iat":1487331776,"acr":"urn:mace:incommon:iap:silver"}
```

By openid connect spec, the iss field is expected to be "https://192.168.1.123:9443/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/" in my case. How can I do to change the iss value of default in idtoken?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set things up before running the wso2 IS server of its first time.
Set IDTokenIssuerID in identity.xml as below first. Then run IS server. The settings will be picked up.

```
<IDTokenIssuerID>${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/</IDTokenIssuerID>
```