# How to change the iss claim in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I need to change the openid issuer

```
 "issuer": "https://gate.domain.com:443/oauth2/token"
```

to this

```
 "issuer": "https://api.domain.com",
```

Also change the JWT iss from

```
"iss": "wso2.org/products/am"
```

to

```
"iss": "https://api.domain.com"
```

I see in the api-manager.xml file a tokenEndPoint tag. I'm not sure altering that end point is the correct why to achieve what I want.

I read in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299198/how-to-change-openid-connect-idtokens-iss) question, which has a similar issue. It said to alter this tag in identity.xml

```
<IDTokenIssuerID>${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}/oauth2/token</IDTokenIssuerID>
```

I've tried altering in both places and my JWT iss claim still return "wso2.org/products/am"

Comment: what is the version of APIM you are trying this out with?

Comment: I'm using APIM 2.1.0

Comment: "wso2.org/products/am" comes in the JWT generated by the KeyManager component which IS NOT an openid connect token.

Comment: in an id_token the default issuer value will be "https://172.17.0.1:9443/oauth2/token" (token endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using a custom JWT Generator, I ended up just overwriting the iss with the static address I needed.